# I need Help To Delete a Directory using DeleteDirectory and DeleteFile API function

Tags: c, winapi

I edit my code but I'm still having the same problem , the files won't delete , and the directory still not deleted , I need Help

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<tchar.h>

 void Delete(WIN32_FIND_DATA x);

int main(int argc , char*argv[])
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA x , d;
    HANDLE f = FindFirstFile(L"d:\\Text\\*.*" , &x);
    if(f == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Serach faild\n");
        return 0;
    }

    Delete(x);

    while(FindNextFile(f , &x))
        Delete(x);

    FindClose(f);

    printf("Now I'm going to delete the Directory\n");
    if(RemoveDirectory(L"d:\\Text"))
        printf("Successed\n");
    else
        printf("Did not\n");
}

 void Delete(WIN32_FIND_DATA x)
 {
    if((x.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == 0)
         {
            _tprintf(L"The first File name is %s\n" , x.cFileName);
            printf("I'm going To delete The File\n");
            if(DeleteFile(L"d:\\Text\\x.cFileName"))
                printf("File Deleted\n");
            else printf("False\n");
         }

    else
            _tprintf(L"The Directory name is %s\n" , x.cFileName);

 }
```

I can't find the problem in this code , I wrote everything I know , can anyone edit it to work , and thanks for everyone

Comment: Do you mean DeleteFile rather than Delete? The shfileoperation API can do all this in a single call

Answer (score 0):

After you delete everything in a directory, it will still contain entries for "." and ".." directories, which can't be deleted (except by deleting the containing directory). As such, your code to delete the directory will never execute, but your second `FindFirstFile` will always show two entries, even after you've successfully deleted everything.

Comment: But my problem is that even the Files inside that folder isn't deleted

Comment: @Lara: do you, perhaps, have some files that have been marked read-only, and/or some other directories contained in the target directory? Your code doesn't seem to anticipate/deal with either.

Comment: Yes it's true because first I'm  writing a simple code then I'm going to deal with the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the code doesn't work is that the Delete function always tries to delete a file called: `d:\\Text\\x.cFileName`

Instead you need something like:

```
        TCHAR buff[MAX_PATH];
        _tprintf(L"The first File name is %s\n" , x.cFileName);
        printf("I'm going To delete The File\n");
        _stprintf(buff, L"d:\\Text\\%s", x.cFileName);
        if(DeleteFile(buff))
            printf("File Deleted\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762164%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in order to delete the directory and all its content.

```
WCHAR FilePath[MAX_PATH+1]=L"D:\\Text";
SHFILEOPSTRUCT Operation={0};
Operation.wFunc=FO_DELETE;
//FilePath needs to be double-null terminated
FilePath[wcslen(FilePath)+1]=L'\0';
Operation.pFrom=FilePath;
//Don't show any user interface during the operation
Operation.fFlags=FOF_SILENT|FOF_NOCONFIRMATION|FOF_NOERRORUI;
if(SHFileOperation(&Operation)==0) {
    printf("The directory has been deleted.");
}
else {
    //Handle error here
}
```